# FInding number of ancestors at given depth

Tags: algorithms, trees

I have a rooted tree with $n$ vertices.

I want to be able to answer the given queries in logarithmic time after setting up some sort of data structure (preferably in time $n\log n$.

The query is given by $v$ and $k$.

I want to find the number of ancestors of $v$ of degree less than or equal to $k$.( I call ancestors of degree $1$ sons).

I don't know how to do it.

At first I thought that I should only store the number of ancestors of $v$ of degree less than $2^j$. But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think I got it, for each integer I save entry time and exit time. then for each vertex I save (height, entry time). Then I want all vertices that are in between (height(v)+1,entrytime(v)) and (height(v)+k,exittime(v)).

Comment: So you order lexicographically the vertices with the criteria (height,entrytime) and you are good to go.

Comment: Did you figure out the answer?  If you don't need an answer to this any longer, I would suggest either writing up the answer, or deleting the question, so that others don't waste time helping you out with something you already know.

Comment: done. :)${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a dfs starting from the root. we save the entry-time and exit time of each vertex. We build a list containing (height(v),entrytime(v)). Where entrytime is the time in the dfs where we first reached vertex v.

we now sort our list lexicographically (this takes time $\mathcal O(n\log(n))$ ) . Inside this order, the vertices at height $h$ that are ancestors of a vertex $v$ are the elements in the list that are between $(h,entrytime(v))$ and $(h,exittime(v))$.

So the problem is essentially reduced to the following:

Suppose we have an array of integers $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$, given $x$ and $p$ how can we find the number of elements in the range $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_p$ that are greater than $x$? (we just need $p-k$).

Various efficient solutions to this are discussed [here:](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22893)

Comment: @D.W. fixed.${}{}{}$

Comment: in fact the link shows how to solve that other problem even if there are updates (we don't need updates)